# How to show image from url in image view directly in android development

Tags: android, image, gridview

what is the best method to display images in grid view from a number of url's?

Comment: Use this library. http://square.github.io/picasso/

Answer (score 1):

Use Picasso library:
1) download jar from: [Link Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) or even better use Gradle -

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

2) and with this code

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```

Picasso will handle all loading and also exceptions.

Comment: thankss but i have got multiple url's for different images to display in grid view.

Comment: than use the code in your adapter class... simple...

Comment: ok i vl give a try and thankss a lot..